# In WP, how can I maintain visible the caret position cursor, without showing the softkeyboard?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soft-keyboard

Its a very unusual question, but I'm in need of this feature. In Windows Phone, how can I maintain visible the caret position cursor of a given TextBox, without showing the softkeyboard (virtual keyboard)? In Android this is very possible, but I haven't found anything in WP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Caret is only visible and associated with focus being on that control. The same applies to Soft keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hermit. Hmm... Microsoft has a realy sad API uhn? Times later I used to develop for Android, and now I'm feeling like chained hands with WP... =/

Comment: WP dev was chained from day 0. In my app slydr, I display dummy caret using | char

Comment: ahah... I gonna try this idea of "| dummy"!

Comment: Hermit, you've said that is using the "|" character a a dummy. How you did this, as different characters have different widths (i.e. "i" and "o")? How you've calculated where to put your "|" character with a show/hide effect?

Comment: in slydr i only tend to show the caret at the end but it does occasionally create very weird effects when its close to end of the line :)